# Getting Issue with jaxb2-maven-plugin while Importing into Project in JDK 1.8

Tags: java, web-services

I am trying to import jaxb2-maven-plugin in to maven project and I am working on JDK 1.8. While importing itself it showing the below errors.

Actually, my requirement is to generate the `xml` to `java` classes by the jaxb2 plugin.

Thanks in Advance.

### ERRORS:

> Execution schemagen of goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:schemagen failed: Plugin 
>    org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find 
>    se.west.converters:custom-jaxb-converters:jar:1.2.14 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the 
>    local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are

Comment: ----------
POM.xml
----------
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions> // here am getting an error
              <execution>
               <id>xjc</id>
               <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal> //here it is showing the error
               </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
      Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments. Code is unreadable in comments. Not all comments may or may not be shown initially.